# How to make query with multi value parameter run faster?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, ssrs-2008

I have the following query that is running very slow:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT a.Role as Role
FROM 
    [Table_A] a 
JOIN 
    [Table_B] b ON (a.Key = b.Key)
WHERE 
    b.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND ISNULL(a.ID, -1) IN (@People)
```

The values of the variables `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` and `@People` come from parameters in a SSRS report. The date parameters are just dates. The `@People` parameter is a multi value parameter.

The problem is that `@People` contains over 3000 values. So the query has to go through it all using the `IN` clause. This really, really slows down my query when running it in SSRS.

I wanted to use an exists clause to replace the `IN` clause but I can't seem to get that to work in this scenario. I'd need to somehow select the values from the `@People` variable in the `EXISTS` clause and join it back to the first table, but I don't even know if that is possible.

Perhaps I am going down the wrong direction with this trying to use the `EXISTS` in this scenario. But I still need to fix the query so it runs faster.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Can you post the execution plans via: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Is that an unwanted AND after WHERE?

Comment: @scsimon, thanks for that. It was an error and I removed the extra AND

Comment: @OhSoConfused I can't get the execution plan so I'll need to get help without it

Comment: What indexes are on the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ISNULL(a.ID, -1)` is going to make the query non-SARGable. You would be better off using `(a.ID IN (@People) OR a.ID IS NULL)`, however, an `IN` with that many arguments is unlikely to run well.

I'm running on memory here (I don't have SSRS at home) but if i recall SSRS does some "magic" with multivalue parameters and `IN` that doesn't scale well. Perhaps you would be better trying to use an `EXISTS` and a splitter (such as [`DelimitedSplit8k`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)). This specific example relies on `@People` having less than 8000 characters.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Role
FROM [Table_A] a 
     JOIN [Table_B] b ON a.Key = b.Key
WHERE b.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
  AND (EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@People,',') DS
               WHERE DS.Item = a.ID)
   OR  a.ID IS NULL);
```

Considering, however, that ordinal position doesn't matter here, then other splitters are available. For example the [XML Splitter](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1771/splitting-delimited-strings-using-xml-in-sql-server/).

*For completeness, a quickly written XML Splitter Function:*

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.XMLSplitter (@DelimitedString varchar(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN

    SELECT n.d.value('.','varchar(MAX)') AS Item
    FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(xml,'<d>'+ REPLACE(@DelimitedString,',','</d><d>') + '</d>'))) V(X)
         CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes('d') n(d);

GO
```

Added a full example without a function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Role
FROM [Table_A] a 
        JOIN [Table_B] b ON a.Key = b.Key
WHERE b.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(xml,'<d>'+ REPLACE(@DelimitedString,',','</d><d>') + '</d>'))) V(X)
                       CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes('d') n(d)
                 WHERE n.d.value('.','varchar(MAX)') = a.ID)
    OR  a.ID IS NULL);
```

Comment: this solution would work wonderful for me but the problem with it is that I cannot implement a custom function. I would need to somehow split the comma delimited values up using a select statement of some kind. Also, I cannot use the built in STRING_SPLIT function either because I'd need to set the database compatibly to 130, which I cannot do due to, again, a permission issue. I would love to use the above solution, but how can I split the string up using only a select statement?

Comment: @Zolt the code for a XML Splitter is in my answer, you could quite easily put that into straight into the main query instead, I only separated it so that it could be reused easily. Have you given it a go? What problems did you have?

Comment: your solution works if I run it in SSMS, but when I put the query into SSRS, run the report, and choose multiple options for @DelimitedString then SSRS give this error: `query execution failed for dataset replace funtion requires 3 arguments`

Comment: @Zolt Give the above a go. You might, otherwise, want to create an SP that the SSRS report can use (forcing it to provide a delimited list instead replacing the variable's name).

Comment: you did not need to combing the query like that. I already did that before. As I mentioned before I got it to work in SSMS but not in SSRS. The issue was that I needed to add `=Join(Parameters!Parameter.Label, ",")` as an express for the Parameter Value in the parameter that uses the above query. Doing that got everything to work.